# Cannot create a backup sql file with mysqldump

Tags: java, mysql

I want to create backup mysql file (table structure + data) . Here is my code:- in cmd.exe

```
mysqldump -u root -p123 mydb > mydump.sql
```

mydb is my database name and password is 123.
Before couple of months, the code snip worked. But now it gives me

```
Access denied
```

In the code, I replaced `>` with `-r` 
Then it says

```
mysqldump: can't create/write to file mydump.sql errcode:13
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200076/mysql-database-backup-with-mysqldump) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345036/transfer-mysql-data-to-a-new-database-structure) are my previous sql questions and they worked well earlier. But now not working. Also I am excited that this following code written in java works well and create a dump sql file.

```
* Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysqldump -u root -p123 mydb -r " + destination);
```

Why can't I write in cmd and create a dump file? My OS is Windows 7 and use KasperSky (now expired and I tried above codes turning off the virus guard.but no change)Any one let me know, where or what the solution is for this?

**Edit**   I think that, the problem might be in the cmd execution. Because, I tried the same codes in a java application through `*Process` (I have mentioned the code above). It WORKED WELL and creates dump files. Still I couldn't find what this errcode13.

Comment: Did you try the modified command in console?

Comment: @ juergen d. Sorry, modified command means ? I m not an expert

Comment: -p does not allow passing password from command line check mysql available switches

Comment: @AashMaharoon: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Did you try the command in the console after replacing the `>` with `-r`?

Comment: @ juergen d. Thanks. Yes, I tried. then it gave `mysqldump: can't create/write to file mydump.sql errcode:13  ` error. I have mentioned in my question too.

Comment: @kappa. Thank you. I m sorry. '-p does not allow passing password... ' but earlier times, it asked me to type the passward. May be I have misunderstood what u mean. Any way let me know about other available switches you mentioned. I am not excellent in sql

Comment: What permissions does your Windows user have on `mydump.sql` and/or the working directory.

Comment: @eggyal. Oh. it is ok :) . user is Admin of my pc

Comment: @Aash Maharoon first check if you have write permissions to `destination` if yes then dump the data there

Comment: @c0mrade . I tried changing the destination path. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cmd /c start mysqldump --user=usr--password=pass-h localhost --databases schemaName -r file.sql
```

and verify mysqldump is in the classpath